# How do I assign permissions to users to see SQL Agent Jobs?

Tags: user-permissions, sql-agent-job

I want to give some developer rights to check if the jobs are complete without granting full admin rights.

I have seen people saying to add the user to  SQLAgentReaderRole role. Is there any additional permission that the role will have other then just viewing job status.

Comment: Could someone please respond on this post?